# Autovacuum on template0 database on AWS RDS postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4

Can we run vacuuming on PostgreSQL's template0 database? If yes, do we really need to or should we?

I am running PG 9.4 and having around billion transactions every 4 - 5 days.

When I run:

```
    SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid) FROM pg_database;

     datname     |    age     
-----------------+------------
 template0       | 1370404693
 rdsadmin        | 1285536968
 template1       |  122255271
 postgres        |  122303483
 bt_prod         |  212084472
(5 rows)
```

As you can see template0 and rdsadmin are perilously close to the 2.1 billion marks and we don't want PostgreSQL to go down because of these databases.

Comment: What is your `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` setting? Is `autovacuum` set to `on`? Any log messages?

Comment: autovacuum_freeze_max_age: 200000000

Yes, Autovacuum is turned on. FYI: I have around 60K tables (PG 9.4 partitions) some of them more than 20 GB.

Comment: With that many tables, you should increase `max_autovacuum_workers` at least to 10. Check `pg_stat_activity` if there are autovaccuum workers running for a long time (old `query_start`). Set `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to 0 to get log messages. I suspect that autovacuum may just not be able to keep up. Tell me your findings.

Comment: There were two issues: 1. All 6 workers were stuck since a long time (~ 16 hours). They were deadlocked on one table each and were not doing anything. I killed it manually. 2. Several settings were not perfect for our workload. I tweaked `max_autovacuum_workers` to 10. Gave more RAM to `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem`, increased `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` to 2500 because I had unused IOPS. I'll write a detailed answer once I get some time. But, I still don't understand the exact reason why the workers were deadlocked.

Comment: Great that you could improve the situation. The workers shouldn't get stuck, but now it's too late to examine the workers with `strace` or `gdb` to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, had less time to get to the root as the situation was getting pretty scary. Thanks for the help!